# Django How can I use redis in Windows10?

Tags: python, django, redis, windows-10

I am developing small system with Django framework and Windows 10. I am going to use Redis for caching on memory. Well, I found that Redis doesn't support Windows OS officially but MsOpenTech provides a package for Windows 64 bit. I installed it with chocolatey package manager. https://chocolatey.org/packages/redis-64

Then I installed django-redis package by pip install in cmd. Well, It automatically installed redis module at the same time. I thought it would be fine to delete redis module because I already installed redis 3.0.503 64 bit(for Win). But it occured error "no mudule named 'redis'". I checked django-redis directory "django_redis-4.5.0-py3.4.egg-info". There was one line 'redis>=2.10.0' in 'requries.text' file. so I assumed django-redis is set to need redis 2.10.0 as default.

well, then I just installed redis by pip install redis in cmd. After setting in Django, I saved some key value data as test on redis. (by using cache_page decorator)

```
CACHES = {
    "default" : {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1",
        "OPTION": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        },
        "KEY_PREFIX": "Test"
    }
}
```

I connected to redis.

```
redis-cli -n 1
```

I checked keys

```
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> keys *
```

result was like this. empty

```
(empty list or set)
```

then I put test data on redis by cache_page decorator to check it. I got this result.

```
1) "Test:1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page..GET.1be77f2243e36ea7e7fa68d85c1c277e.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.en-us.Korea_Standard_Time"
2) "Test:1:views.decorators.cache.cache_header..1be77f2243e36ea7e7fa68d85c1c277e.en-us.Korea_Standard_Time"
```

I checked it with get command.it is supposed to show rendered HTML string.

```
get "Test:1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page..GET.1be77f2243e36ea7e7fa68d85c1c277e.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.en-us.Korea_Standard_Time"
```

The result like below seems alright.

```
"\x80\x04\x95\xe8\a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x14django.http.response\x94\x8c\x0cHttpResponse\x94\x93\x94)}\x94\x92\x94}\x94(\x8c\x06closed\x94\x89\x8c\b_charset\x94N\x8c\x0e_handler_class\x94N\x8c\b_headers\x94}\x94(\x8c\x0ccontent-type\x94\x8c\x0cContent-Type\x94\x8c\x18text/html; charset=utf-8\x94\x86\x94\x8c\aexpires\x94\x8c\aExpires\x94\x8c\x1dMon, 10 Oct 2016 09:32:19 GMT\x94\x86\x94\x8c\rcache-control\x94\x8c\rCache-Control\x94\x8c\nmax-age=60\x94\x86\x94\x8c\rlast-modified\x94\x8c\rLast-Modified\x94\x8c\x1dMon, 10 Oct 2016 09:31:19 GMT\x94\x86\x94u\x8c\x0e_reason_phrase\x94N\x8c\acookies\x94\x8c\x0chttp.cookies\x94\x8c\x0cSimpleCookie\x94\x93\x94)}\x94\x92\x94\x8c\x11_closable_objects\x94]\x94\x8c\n_container\x94]\x94B/\x06\x00\x00<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"ko\">\n\n<head>\n<title>Menu front page</title>\n</head>\n\n<body>\n<div id=\"context_processor_test\">\n\t<ul>\n\t\t<li>[&lt;Menu: root&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xed\x98\x84\xed\x99\xa9\xeb\xb6\x84\xec\x84\x9d&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xec\x9e\xac\xea\xb3\xa0\xed\x98\x84\xed\x99\xa9&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xed\x98\x84\xec\x9e\xac \xec\x9e\xac\xea\xb3\xa0&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xea\xb8\xb0\xea\xb0\x84\xec\x9e\xac\xea\xb3\xa0 \xec\xa1\xb0\xed\x9a\x8c&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xec\x9e\xac\xea\xb3\xa0\xea\xb8\xb0\xea\xb4\x80 \xec\xa1\xb0\xed\x9a\x8c&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xec\x9e\xac\xea\xb3\xa0 \xed\x9a\x8c\xec\xa0\x84\xec\x9c\xa8 \xec\xa1\xb0\xed\x9a\x8c&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xeb\xa7\xa4\xec\x9e\x85\xeb\xa7\xa4\xec\xb6\x9c \xeb\xb6\x84\xec\x84\x9d&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xea\xb8\xb0\xea\xb0\x84\xeb\xb3\x84 \xed\x98\x84\xed\x99\xa9&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xec\x83\x81\xed\x92\x88\xeb\xb3\x84 \xed\x98\x84\xed\x99\xa9&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xea\xb1\xb0\xeb\x9e\x98\xed\x98\x95\xed\x83\x9c\xeb\xb3\x84 \xed\x98\x84\xed\x99\xa9&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xec\x82\xac\xec\x97\x85\xeb\xb6\x80\xeb\xb3\x84 \xed\x98\x84\xed\x99\xa9&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xea\xb1\xb0\xeb\x9e\x98\xec\xb2\x98\xeb\xb3\x84 \xed\x98\x84\xed\x99\xa9&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xec\x9e\x91\xec\x97\x85\xed\x98\x84\xed\x99\xa9&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xec\x9e\x91\xec\x97\x85\xec\x9a\x94\xec\xb2\xad \xed\x98\x84\xed\x99\xa9&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xea\xb2\x80\xec\x88\x98\xec\x9a\x94\xec\xb2\xad&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xec\x83\x81\xed\x92\x88\xed\x99\x94 \xec\x9a\x94\xec\xb2\xad&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xec\xa0\x9c\xed\x92\x88\xed\x99\x94 \xec\x9a\x94\xec\xb2\xad&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xec\x97\xbd\xec\x97\x89\xea\xb4\x80\xeb\xa6\xac&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xeb\x82\xb4\xeb\xb6\x80\xec\xb2\x98\xeb\xa6\xac&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xed\x8c\x90\xeb\xa7\xa4\xea\xb4\x80\xeb\xa6\xac&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xea\xb5\xac\xeb\xa7\xa4\xea\xb4\x80\xeb\xa6\xac&gt;, &lt;Menu: \xed\x99\x98\xea\xb2\xbd\xec\x84\xa4\xec\xa0\x95&gt;]</li>\n\t</ul>\n</div>\n\n<div id=\"context_processor_test2\">\n\t<ul>\n\t\t<li>&lt;QuerySet [&lt;UserInfo: dkjfadl&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: fidlajf&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: fjialejgljadf&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: dfialghelfdja&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: dkajlf&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: testgroup&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: dfjlda&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: fjdalfiagda&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: remann&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: aldfjdalfj&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: dlkajflad&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: dkajfldafj&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: djafldijfl&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: testgroup&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: &lt;bound method Group.__str__ of &lt;Group: remann&gt;&gt;&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: remann&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: testgroup&gt;, &lt;UserInfo: testgroup&gt;]&gt;</li>\n\t</ul>\n</div>\n<!--\n<div id=\"top_menu\">\n\t\n</div>\n-->\n\n\n\n\n</body>\n</html>\n\n\x94aub."
```

Because my templete code is like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">

<head>
<title>{% block title %}Menu front page{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="context_processor_test">
    <ul>
        <li>{{ menu_list }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="context_processor_test2">
    <ul>
        <li>{{ user_info_list }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--
<div id="top_menu">
    {% for top_menu in root.get_children %}
    <ul style="display:inline-block;">
        <li><a href="{{top_menu.menu_alias}}"> {{ top_menu.menu_name }} </a></li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
-->
{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

My question are

1) Is it okay to use redis on Windows with this setting? I wonder if it works properly.

2) I wonder why it named like "Test:1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page..GET.1be77f2243e36ea7e7fa68d85c1c277e.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.en-us.Korea_Standard_Time" instead of just "Test:1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page"

well, my question could be not well explained or out of point.
Just let me know if you need to know more in detail or properly.

I hope there are some people have similar issues with Windows OS to deal with Redis and Django!

Thank you for reading!

Comment: You're confusing two things here. The "redis" installed by chocolatey is the actual Redis database server; the "redis" installed by pip (and automatically brought in by django-redis) is the Python client library. You do need both; but since you now have both and everything is working, I'm not sure what you're actually asking.

Comment: Also note that since Windows 10 now includes a full Ubuntu environment, you might find it easier to do your development there (from where you could do `apt-get install redis` to install the redis server).

Comment: @DanielRoseman At first, I didn't know that redis which was installed automatically with django-redis package was just Python client library. It had different version(Redis win 64 is 3.X.X and Redis by pip install was 2.X.X) So I thought two different version Redis were installed and I was worried that it conflicts when I want to do more serious stuffs with it later. I am realizing that It doesn't seem very nice to keep using only Window Os to develope. I considered of using Bash with update of Win10 because I am using win 10. Thanks for comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You uninstalled the Python `redis` package thinking it was the Redis server but it's just a Python package with code to *access* Redis. You need to reinstall it. But you seem to have that part fixed.

As for using Redis with Django on Windows 10 the way you installed it, I would say it depends on what you want to do. If you just want to play around with it to learn, you should be fine. On the other hand, if you want to do some more serious development, I would install Redis another way. Here are a few possibilities I can think of:

- Installing Linux in a virtual machine with VirtualBox, VMWare or something like that, and install Redis in there;
- Windows 10 now has the possibility of running Ubuntu Linux in it, so perhaps installing Redis there is the easiest option;
- Use a Docker container to run Redis (use Docker for Windows: https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/ then you can get the Redis image from here: https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/)

Finally, regarding why the cache entries have those names, the default key Django cache creates for cache entries is defined [here (django/core/cache/backends/base.py:27)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/cache/backends/base.py#L27):

```python
def default_key_func(key, key_prefix, version):
    """
    Default function to generate keys.

    Constructs the key used by all other methods. By default it prepends
    the `key_prefix'. KEY_FUNCTION can be used to specify an alternate
    function with custom key making behavior.
    """
    return '%s:%s:%s' % (key_prefix, version, key)
```

In your case the key is `Test:1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page..GET.1be77f2243e36ea7e7fa68d85c1c277e.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.en-us.Korea_Standard_Time`, so that gives us the following breakdown:

```
key_prefix = Test
version = 1
key = views.decorators.cache.cache_page..GET.1be77f2243e36ea7e7fa68d85c1c277e.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.en-us.Korea_Standard_Time
```

If you have a look in [`django/views/decorators/cache.py:10`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/decorators/cache.py#L10) you can see how the key part is composed. Specifically, this:

> The cache is keyed by the URL and some data from the headers.

The extra stuff you see there beyond what you were expecting is the headers data from the request.

Comment: Thanks for answer. it helped a lot! Well, I am working with Win10. I push my work to GitHub. and actually my unbuntu server will operate this code by pulling over from GitHub. all people around me are using Mac. well, I considered of updating my Win10 to use bash actually. but I was little bit worried that it is not stable yet to upgrade because kind of alert notice popped up before upgrading such as checkbox if you know how to backup and reinstall well. I don't know if it is good idea but I wanted to keep using Win environment to experience both side because anyway I use Ubuntu

Comment: But it is little bit annoying. because JackIll says that they don't support Windows officially in document, Redis says that they also don't support Windows officially in site. People who work with me are all using Mac. (I am just beginner of working as a developer) Have you ever had experience with work together with people using Windows?

Comment: If you are doing serious development work, then I strongly suggest you drop Windows for running your code. You will most likely deploy your code to a Linux server, so you should develop under Linux. You can use any operating system to write your code but run it under Linux (or whatever OS it will be running on in production). I prefer to use Linux directly (currently Linux Mint 18, which is based on Ubuntu 16.04) but you can also use macOS and run Linux in a virtual machine or inside Docker containers. Just don't run it on Windows, there are too many differences that can bite your ass later.

Comment: I will keep your advice in mind. Thanks! Have a nice day!